# Image is uploaded in the folder. But can't view in the browser

Tags: php, jquery, error-handling, image-uploading

I have used a built in plugin for image uploading. Uploaded images are in the folder of the selected path. They are not corrupted. But unfortunately when I clicked the image link in the browser it gives me a error saying "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)".

[image: Screenshot of images after uploading]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are the images being uploaded, but you don't see them when you click the link? If so, you need to add the full path in your php script to the image folder before trying to show the image

Comment: Thank you very much for your concern samayo. Finally I was able to fix that error. Error was with the wamp server and images displayed correctly when I include header modules in apache.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, then please describe your answer as it might be helpful for others with similar issues.

Comment: Sure, I ll do @kolunar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix the issue.

### **Issue**

After uploaded the images I could found them under the folder. But when I clicked them I got an internal server error(500).

### **Solution**

I went to the specific folder and checked that uploaded images. None of them were damaged. But they didn't display correctly on the browser. It was because of an error in the header of htaccess file.

> But error was fixed when I selected the header module in the apache.
>
> Steps to follow
>
> 1. Left click on wamp icon.
> 2. Select Apache.
> 3. Then select Apache Modules.
> 4. Select headers_module.